# Python-based discord bot reply errors (infinite loop)

Tags: python, deep-learning, discord

I've been learning java for a few months and is quite new to python. I'm currently building a simple deep learning AI bot for discord that takes a message from the user, then replies with a message from a pre-established database. I've managed to complete the AI with no issues but I'm currently encountering some problems with setting up the code for discord.

Below is my final code block responsible for receiving the message from discord and replying the user in discord.

**Current Error:** My code wouldn't stop from executing after sending its first message in the discord chat, causing the bot to repeatedly send messages nonstop. This is most likely caused by the `while` loop within the function.

**My attempted solution:** New to python, I'm not sure how I create a boolean type class variable the way you would do it in java. I attempted to use the boolean variable `new_message` as the conditional statement for the while loop. This variable is set to false once a reply by the bot is sent to ensure that the program does not scan the bot's own reply and cause an infinite loop. This solution didn't seem to work because I couldn't seem to figure out a way to create the `new_message` variable outside of the function.

Note: I can't simply remove the while loop because I need the program to terminate once the user enters the input "quit".

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
     bot_testing = client.get_channel(0000000000)
     user_input = message.content
     new_message = True

  while new_message:
    if user_input.lower() == "quit": # type quit to stop the program
        print("Program Terminated")
        break

    results = model.predict([bag_of_words(user_input, words)])[0]
    results_index = numpy.argmax(results) # returns the greatest value's index
    tag = labels[results_index]

    print(results)
    print(tag)

    if results[results_index] > 0.9: # accuracy threshold for a database reply
        for tg in data["replyData"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
                responses = tg['responses']

        await bot_testing.send(random.choice(responses))
        new_message = False
    else:
        await bot_testing.send("I'm not sure I understand. Please try again or ask a different question!")
        new_message = False

client.run('some-bot-code')
```

Also, in addition to the problem above, if anyone knows how to set up a bot that only responds when the bot itself is tagged by a user, please let me know how that is done!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your code is supposed to work. No matter what happens, `new_message` is always `False` after one iteration...

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure what your code is supposed to do, I firmly believe the infinite loop you see is not caused by your `while` loop but by your `on_message` handler. Basically, the bot sees your message, sends another message in response, sees that messages, sends another message in response, etc.

What you can do to avoid that is something like

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # Also desirable
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    # Process user message
```